# AMD graphics card, partially shows artifacts, even before windows load

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, amd-graphics-card

I have in a desktop pc, an AMD HD 7700 series card, and i have installed the latest driver. Sometimes, everything works ok, but other times, when i turn on the pc, even the bios info, shown in the beginning, has artifacts...

What could be the cause for this?

It only happens from time to time, not always.

Answer (score 1):

If it happens at BIOS initialization screen, it can be the cable between the card and the PC or corrupted video memory. Make sure the cable is properly attached and test with another cable. If it's the video memory, you will have to RMA the card (but such situations are more rare than a few years back).

Comment: what i do not understand, is why it is happening occasionally. If it was the cable,  how is it that some times, it works fine, while others, it has an issue? Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: Cable can move pretty easy and affect connectivity. If it were memory corruption it would most like manifest more in GUI mode and in BIOS-mode as soon as it would heat up a little or from start but each time.